# Installing Anaconda package behind firewall

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch

I am behind various firewalls at work and trying to install pytorch. Normally I can just download the `tar.gz` file and install it directly, but when I do this now I get this error message:

```
---
CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url <https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2>

An HTTP errors occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
----
```

Are there any way to avoid it going to any websites to download and just install from the locally installed `tar.gz` file?

I can't use conda install or any of the other standard installation methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the appropriate tar file [here](https://anaconda.org/soumith/pytorch/files)

Then run this:

```
<absolute path to python.exe> -m pip install <path to tar.gz>
```

For example:

```
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\python.exe -m pip install c:\mymodule\great.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thanks, but this also gives me an error?

Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module> 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tokenize.py", line 452, in open
buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\nicje\\A
ppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-c68kl3v7-build\\setup.py'

Comment: @NicolajJeppesen That is a completely different problem so you must post it as a different problem.